# How to control webpage with Alexa skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I want to change a website page image or background image with an Alexa voice skill. My current thinking is a meteor website since it dynamically refreshes the client web page and store the different image URLs in a MongoDB.  How do I handle the http request to the meteor webpage so that it will change the image to be displayed?  I have setup and tested general Alexa skills and also setup a simple meteor website (those were the easy parts) on AWS.

Comment: this link [github](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-cookbook/tree/master/aws/Amazon-IOT) solves the problem with a different approach. I then edited the updateDom.js file to change the var ImgUrl to whatever webpage I want displayed

Comment: that worked very well. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd setup a skill service using AWS Lambda and have the Lambda function make an HTTP request to an API endpoint on the meteor website that made the change. It would be fairly simple to setup. The hard part might be getting the user experience right if there are a lot of possible changes that could be made.